# what's equivalent to gcc inline assembler.byte directive in VC++ assembly?

Tags: visual-c++, gcc, assembly

in gcc inline assembly
I can specify pure bytes with

.byte

directive.
e.g

```
.byte 0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc
```

like this.

what is the equivalent in VC++ 2010 inline assembly(intel style)?
the following code gives me error that
byte is a reserved keyword or something...

```
int _tmain(int argc, char ∗argv[])
{
    _asm{
        .byte 0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't output streams of data using inline asm in MSVC.

However if you just want to output a few specific bytes into your assembly code, you can use the `_emit` keyword.

```
_asm {
    _emit 0xcc
    _emit 0xcc
    _emit 0xcc
}
```